# Constructing a JSON from its path

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON document:

```
{
    Customer: {
        Name: "ddd",
        Address: [
            {Line1: "ABC", zip: [{d:"aa"},{d:"hh"} ,{d:"kk"}]},
            {Line1: "XYZ", zip: [{d:"gg"},{d:"ff"}]}
        ]
    }
}
```

I want the values of

```
[
    "Customer.Address.0.Line1",
    "Customer.Address.0.zip.0.d",
    "Customer.Address.0.zip.1.d",
    "Customer.Address.1.Line1",
    "Customer.Address.1.zip.0.d",
    "Customer.Address.1.zip.1.d"
]
```

modified into a new format as below

```
{
    Entity: [
        {d:"aa", Line1:ABC},
        {d:"hh", Line1:ABC},
        {d:"kk", Line1:ABC},
        {d:"gg", Line1:XYZ},
        {d:"ff", Line1:XYZ}
    ]
}
```

I actually need the data as below

```
{
    "Entity.0.d":"aa",
    "Entity.0.Line1":"ABC",
    "Entity.1.d":"hh",
    "Entity.1.Line1":"ABC",
    "Entity.2.d":"kk",
    "Entity.2.Line1":"ABC",
    "Entity.3.d":"gg",
    "Entity.3.Line1":"XYZ",
    "Entity.4.d":"ff",
    "Entity.4.Line1":"XYZ"
}
```

I need to find the path so that I can reconstruct the JSON.
How do I do that?

Comment: I don't entirely understand how the "paths" are translated into the final object. The result just seems to be a mapping of each `zip` element to its corresponding `Line1` element. What does the array of strings do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var newJSON = new Object();
var keyArray = [];
for (var i=0; i< Customer.Address.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j< Customer.Address[i].zip.length; j++){
        var innerJSON = new Object();
        innerJSON.d = Customer.Address[i].zip[j].d;
        innerJSON.Line1 = Customer.Address[i].Line1;
        keyArray.push(innerJSON);
    }
}

newJSON.key = keyArray;
console.log(JSON.stringify(newJSON)); //This line creates your new JSON string
```

Of course I am assuming that you have used JSON.parse on your first JSON string :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit - missed the index on that! Please mark the answer as correct if it helps you :)

Comment: `Customer.Address[i].zip.length` is returning undefined and the final output is empty. Like `{"key":[]}`.

Comment: @sivatumma:you need to parse the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotty](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty)

```
var dotty = require("dotty");

var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      x: "y",
    },
    c: {
      x: "z",
    },
  },
};

console.log(dotty.exists(object, "a.b.x")); // true
console.log(dotty.exists(object, ["a", "b", "x"])); // true
console.log(dotty.exists(object, "a.b.z")); // false
console.log(dotty.exists(object, ["a", "b", "z"])); // false

console.log(dotty.get(object, "a.b.x")); // "y"
console.log(dotty.get(object, ["a", "b", "x"])); // "y"
console.log(dotty.get(object, "a.b.z")); // undefined
console.log(dotty.get(object, ["a", "b", "z"])); // undefine
```

Comment: actually im planning to use flat module.Thats the reason why i need the path so that flat module can construct the JSON object

Comment: How can i use the dotty module to parse a array of objects?